# Must Alice provide ingredients for baked goods she sells produced by a third party

Tags: england-and-wales, consumer-protection, food, nutrition

Alice’s Restaurant sells pastries prepared by Bob’s bakery but when asked for ingredients listing she suggests that a customer look at Bob’s bakery’s website or if that fails then even looking to its phone number to call and enquire to him directly. Mustn’t Alice as the seller of the product supply ingredients and allergens lists?

Comment: **how** does she sell the pastries? As a meal or packaged?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

Alice's Restaurant is not required to provide information about all the ingredients in non-prepacked food.

Alice's Restaurant is required to provide allergen information about any item that contains any of the 13 allergens ([Article 44 Regulation (EU) No 1169/2011](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/eur/2011/1169/article/44) (aka FIC) read with [point (c) of Article 9(1)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/eur/2011/1169/chapter/IV) FIC).

The information can be provided in writing or orally ([s5 The Food Information Regulations 2014](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2014/1855/regulation/5)). If it is to be provided orally, there must be clear and visible 'signposting' e.g. [a written notice such as](https://www.food.gov.uk/sites/default/files/media/document/Allergen%20and%20Intolerance%20sign%20%28Colour%29.pdf):

> If you have a food allergy, intolerance, or coeliac disease – please
> speak to the staff about the ingredients in your food and drink before
> you order.

Every Food Business Operator (FBO) at each stage of production to sale is responsible for providing the information to the next stage ([Articles 6, 7 and 8](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/eur/2011/1169/article/8) FIC).

Alice's Restaurant is responsible for providing the information about the products it sells to its customers.

As Trish commented, it is Bob's responsibility to provide Alice with the allergen information so that Alice can provide the information to the customer.

This may be of interest:
[Food Standards Agency: Food allergen labelling and information requirements technical guidance: Part 2: Guidance for businesses providing non-prepacked food](https://www.food.gov.uk/business-guidance/food-allergen-labelling-and-information-requirements-technical-guidance-part-2-guidance-for-businesses-providing-non-prepacked)

Comment: Or said differently: It is Bob's responsibility to provide Alice with the Allergy information so Alice can inform the customer?

Answer (score 3):

### No

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia) and [new-zealand](/questions/tagged/new-zealand) have common food labeling laws. The NSW Government provides a simple [quiz](https://www.foodauthority.nsw.gov.au/food-labelling/do-i-need-food-label) to determine if a label is required. Based on your description, the answer is no.

Alice must be able to provide allergen information on request.